# How do I keep the active tab after page refresh with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

```
  // show the section active
  $('div>a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
    $('.main.container>section').removeClass('active')
    $('.main.container>section.' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('active')
  })
```

I want to make this code work with localstorage so that it shows the active tab after page refresh.
I've tried others one in stackoverflow but they did not work for my case. Maybe I did not fully understand with localstorage thing. Plz let me know if there is another way to make it work. Any help would be appritiated.

Here's url I've been practicing on. https://jsfiddle.net/fnx5y4h8/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a localStorage item called "tab" whenever you select a tab. Then, whenever the page loads, check if that localStorage item exists. If it does, select that tab.

```js
// show the section active
$('div>a').click(function() {
  selectTab($(this).attr('id'));
  localStorage.setItem("tab", $(this).attr('id'))
})

// On load
const loadedTab = localStorage.getItem("tab");
if (loadedTab) {
  selectTab(loadedTab);
}

function selectTab(tabId) {
  $('.main.container>section').removeClass('active')
  $('.main.container>section.' + tabId).addClass('active')
}
```

Comment: It worked .  Thanks !